# Javascript: how to find child nodes by element name instead of XML tree position?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a working example. Currently, I'm finding the child node values by their supposed position in the node tree, but because sometimes there are missing nodes, this method doesn't work flawlessly. What's the simplest way to find the child nodes by the element name instead of XML tree position?

```js
var n = document.getElementById("myInputId");
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("myButton").click();
  }
});

function testResults() {
  const { value } = myInputId;
  const foundState = [...xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('STATE')]
    .find(possibleMatch => possibleMatch.textContent === value);
  const unit = foundState.parentElement;
  console.log(unit.innerHTML);
  document.getElementById("stateNode").innerHTML =     unit.children[0].textContent;
  document.getElementById("gdpNode").innerHTML = unit.children[1].textContent;
  document.getElementById("populationNode").innerHTML = unit.children[2].textContent;
/*how can I find a node based on its name rather than position in the XML tree?*/
  document.getElementById("codeNode").innerHTML = unit.children[3].textContent;
}

var parser, xmlDoc, x, i;
var text =
  "<STATE_DATA>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>Wisconsin</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>232,300,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>5,800,000</POPULATION>" +
  "<CODE>WI</CODE>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>Alabama</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>165,800,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>4,900,000</POPULATION>" +
  "<CODE>AL</CODE>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>California</STATE>" +
  /*California is missing the GDP node*/
  "<POPULATION>39,600,000</POPULATION>" +
  "<CODE>CA</CODE>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>Texas</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>1,600,000,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>28,300,000</POPULATION>" +
  "<CODE>TX</CODE>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>Michigan</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>382,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>10,000,000</POPULATION>" +
  "<CODE>MI</CODE>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "</STATE_DATA>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="testResults()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
<option id="AL">Alabama</option>
<option id="CA">California</option>
<option id="MI">Michigan</option>
<option id="TX">Texas</option>
<option id="WI">Wisconsin</option>
</datalist>

<p>State node: <span id="stateNode"></span></p>
<p>GDP node: <span id="gdpNode"></span></p>
<p>Population node: <span id="populationNode"></span></p>
<p>Code node: <span id="codeNode"></span></p>
```

Comment: This seems to work but it's kinda messy and could do with cleaning up hence not posting as a solution/answer but I hope this helps [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/n5zvyqcL/ Notice the changes to the `HTML` too. I have added a `class` to `span` tags to clear the current `textContent` and used the query results to target the element `ID's`

Comment: Why not post it as an answer? Looks like an elegant solution.

Comment: @NewToJS Can you explain what this does? `forEach(v=>{v.innerHTML="";`

Comment: Because I have added a `class` to the result `span` tag I am using that to loop/iterate through the class/group/collection of elements to clear the `innerHTML/textContent`. The reason I added that is because if you change the option and a result is missing it will still display the previous content in the missing span. I am using the XML tag names to target the spans.

Comment: I like this solution. Last question: where is `v` from `v.innerHTML`  defined?

Comment: `v` is used as the current/target item from the collection of results and is given to the function as parameter. Just like using `onClick="MyFunction(this)"` passing the element used to trigger the function but in the `forEach` it will use `v` as current target. If you add `console.log(v);` and open the browser console you will see what `v` contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, using node position isn't generally a reliable approach. Depending on the size of your XML structure I'd recommend use a sub-`querySelector` from the Unit node:

You already have the UNIT node (`const unit = foundState.parentElement;`) , so just set up something like this:

```
   var ustate = unit.querySelector('STATE') ? unit.querySelector('STATE').textContent: "Not Found";
   var ugdp = unit.querySelector('GDP') ? unit.querySelector('GDP').textContent: "Not Found";
...
```

Then update your HTML:

```
  document.getElementById("stateNode").innerHTML =    ustate ;
  document.getElementById("gdpNode").innerHTML = ugdp ;
```

Comment: Thanks @BenD. You mentioned "depending on the size of the XML structure." Is this not an efficient solution for large XML docs?